# Why every time I use the Arrays modifier with Object Offset, the duplicates begin to increase in size exponentially?

Tags: modifiers

Every time I use the Array modifier with Object Offset, when I increase the count over 1, the duplicates begin to increase in size exponentially. How can I keep their size constant?

Comment: I was unaware of that. Sorry. The answer to the original question was helpful though. Thanks.